# Работа с файлами.

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!

Задача: нужно открыть файл, округлить в меньшую сторону все дробные числа содержащиеся в файле и записать округленные результаты на мест не округленных. Вот что набросал:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            int count=0;
            String[] news = new String [1000];
            int k=0;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                    String regex, s; 
                    double i=scanner.nextDouble();
                    count++;
                    news[k] = (new Double( i )).toString();//scanner.next();
                    k++;

                } else {
                    if (scanner.hasNext()){
                        String i=scanner.next();
                        news[k] = i;//scanner.next();
                        k++;                        
                    }
                    scanner.next();// смещаемся чтобы не зависнуть
                }
            }
            FileWriter wrt;
            wrt = new FileWriter(file);
            String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            for(int i=0; i<k;i++){
                wrt.append(news[i]+lineSeparator);
            }
            wrt.flush();
            wrt.close();
            System.out.println("doubles count: " + count);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Файл считывается, обрабатывается, и записывается... Проблема в считывании, записи и обработке( Я ума не приложу как всё это можно провернуть... Думаю, что в джаве это должно как-то просто делаться. Может у кого есть идеи, наброски?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Файл считывается, обрабатывается, и записывается.
> > Проблема в считывании, записи и обработке

Что у вас конкретно не получается ? Считывание чисел, их округление или запись в файл ?

---

Задача не сложная и состоит из 3 этапов, которые желательно сделать разными методами.
Вот как бы сделал я(на скорую руку :))

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class NumbersTask {

    private File destinationFile;
    private String result;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumbersTask task = new NumbersTask();
        task.setDestinationFile(new File("test.txt"));
        task.doAllWork();
    }

    public void doAllWork() {

        String data = null;
        try {
            data = readFile();                             //1. Чтение
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem reading file");
            //.....
        }
        processNumbers(data);                              //2.  Обработка
        try {
            writeToFile();                                 //3.  Запись
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem writing file");
            //.....
        }

    }

    String readFile() throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(destinationFile));
        StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.append(line);
            lines.append("\n");
        }
        return lines.toString();
    }

    void processNumbers(String data) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)\\.[0-9]+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(data);

        while (m.find()) {
            data = data.replaceAll(m.group(), m.group(1));
        }
        this.result = data;

    }

    void writeToFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(destinationFile));
        for (String line : result.split("\\n")) {
            pw.println(line);
        }
        pw.close();
    }

    public void setDestinationFile(File destinationFile) {
        this.destinationFile = destinationFile;
    }
}
```

До запуска программы файл test.txt выглядит следующим образом:

```
12
12
33.44 bla

IT'S SHOWTIME
TALK TO THE HAND "hello world"
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED

1.22 bla bla text text
1
```

После

```
12
12
33 bla

IT'S SHOWTIME
TALK TO THE HAND "hello world"
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED

1 bla bla text text
1
```

PS: Изменить программу было достаточно легко, так как методы выполняли только 1 задачу

Comment: Начну сначала: У меня считываются числа и текст. Но пробелы не считываются почему-то.

Comment: @Alerr, если я правильно понял

Comment: А почему бы `readFile()` не возвращать сразу массив?

Comment: @VladD, каждый метод должен выполнять свой узкий кусок работы.

Comment: Не совсем то, программа должна "править" текстовый файл. Открывает, ищет числа, округляет(заменяет исходные на округленные). Загвоздка именно в том чтобы править-округлять числа и вписывать в txt. Не нужно удалять остальной текст. Вот в этом так сказать проблемище(

Comment: @Alerr, тогда регулярки, щяс набросаю. Смотри обновление.

Comment: @wwvv: вообще-то, прочитать файл построчно — тоже валидный «узкий кусок». На .NET для него, например, есть отдельный метод.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Изучаю код)